QGIS map properties clip
Does anyone know how to do a properties clip QGIS that will clip all features to a certain feature boundary without actually creating a new feature? It just masks everything outside of of the target feature like you can do in ArcGIS Pro. The Pro seps look like this:


As far as I know there are no native clip functionality in QGIS similar as the one in ArcGIS PRO. You may use the inverted polygon renderer on your feature to create a mask (it wont mask label) or try the Mask plugin (https://github.com/aeag/mask), I had never used it but it seem to give a result closer to the Arc Pro fonction...

You could insert a check for every vector layer, whether the feature falls within your AOI, or outside - and set transparency to 100 % for everything outside the AOI.

The inverted polygon might not mask labels, but the mask plugin can. When masking labels, it does not discriminate between labels inside or outside the AOI.
